# When is a Provider in flutter initialized?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

As mentioned in the title, I'd appreciate it if someone can explain to me the lifecycle of a Provider in flutter.

Basically, in some instances, I needed to add some processing inside a provider constructor. But I noticed that the constructor was called twice, which means that the processing that's happening inside the constructor happened twice.

The problem that I'm facing is, where does the provider get initialized exactly?

I had an example like it's shown below, where I call a method inside the constructor. This method calls another method inside for getting data from my database.

```
ChatFlowData(){
  reload();
}

Future<void> reload() async {
  _user = types.User(id: NO_USER_ID_FOUND);
  _chatgptUser = types.User(id: NO_CHATGPT_USER_ID_FOUND);

  dataHasBeenFetched = false;
  _localUserId = LocalStorageHandler.getValue("userId") ?? NO_USER_ID_FOUND;

  await getDatabaseData();
  dataHasBeenFetched = true;

  notifyListeners();
}

Future<void> getDatabaseData() async {
  try {
    var usersRef = _firebaseDB.collection("users/");
    // ...
  }
```

Now, I use this `ChatFlowData` provider in many places in my code and I can't share all of them here.

So my question again is, in which places does the provider class get initialized?

Is it where I call this `Provider.of<ChatFlowData>`? or when I register the provider?

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => ChatFlowData(),
),
```

I'm probably misunderstanding a basic functionality on how providers work in Flutter. So if anyone can shed some light on this, it would be great!